# Laravel Blade conditional sections

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade

I want to show in my view one section if conditional is true, other section if it is false. I am using PhpStorm as IDE and what I get in those cases is that directive is not closed:

```
@if (conditional)
    @section('content')
        ...
    @stop

@else
    @include('pages.something')
@endif
```

I am getting that opening `@if` is not closed, and that `@else` is missing opening directive.

Front-end works fine, but this is really bugging me in IDE. Can it be resolved?

EDIT:

This only happens when using conditionals and sections together. Conditionals and includes work fine.

Comment: IDE version used? Try 2017.3 EAP build if you are on 2017.2.x or older one. If still the same -- you would need to create a ticket at PhpStorm's [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) for them to fix that -- quite possibly the current implementation of blade directives does not think that such usage is valid (e.g. I'm having a `@section` inside another `@section` .. and it works .. but IDE complains about it)

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your content using @yield

See laravel's docs for reference. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#template-inheritance

Comment: It is already wrapped, this is extended from main layout file

Comment: Have there been any further developments with this in blade since 2017?  I really want a conditional if/else type scenario for some content that may/may not exist depending on the page of my site.